# c# Check for TLS 1,3 support for the host

Tags: c#, ssl, tcpclient

Im trying to get a host's highest supported tls version e.g google.com. but so far no luck. I could use tcp client to check but it is only possible in windows 11 and windows server 2022. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I note that TLS is meant to negotiate the highest supported security level by both ends of a connection anyway by default, so... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Dai I have a vpn server thatuses reality protocol and that protocol needs tls1.3 to use as sni im trying to scan hosts with tls1.3 enabled

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "scan hosts"? The SNi exposure in TLS1.3 is entirely mitigated by using a VPN anyway - so your post doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Let me just put it this way i have a big list of hosts and i want to check which one of them supports tls1.3

Comment: ...so try to connect to each of them using TLS1.3 - `SslStream` has methods to require specific TLS versions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclient?view=net-7.0

Comment: i did that as i said in my question but it is only available in windows 11/windows server 2022. im looking for a workaroound to get it to work on oervioud versions of windows